# How do I concatenate all items from listB onto all items from listA?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I'm trying to figure out how to create an Ansible list that is the result of appending every string from listB onto every string in listA, effectively multiplying two lists of strings together.

In python I'd do this:

```
["-".join((x, y)) for x in listA for y in listB]
```

In other languages I'd nest one `for` loop inside another.

I can't figure out an analogue to this in Ansible.

My reason for doing this is to allow a role to automatically determine the site a host is in.  All of my hosts are in at least one group named for the physical location and the type of site (development, staging, production).  So for example, the New York production site's group would be "nyc-prod".  I need my playbook to be able to pick out the site name from the complete list of groups the host is in.

Given a list of all possible sites, I can intersect that list with the list of groups a host is in, and the resulting single-element list would contain the current hosts's site.

I could brute force this by hand-writing a list of all possible site-type combinations into `group_vars/all` or `vars/main.yml` in a role, but with a large number of sites this multiplies out to a massive list that would have to be maintained.  So my approach has been to try to programmatically construct the list from the much shorter list of physical sites and the list of types.

If I could embed arbitrary python in a jinja template I could do something like this in `tasks/main.yml`:

```
# sites contains a list of all physical locations ['nyc', 'sfo', ...]

- name: get groups
  debug:
    var: group_names
  register: groups

- name: find my site group
  set_fact:
    my_site: "{% site for site in {{groups}} if site in ['-'.join((x, y)) for x in {{sites}} for y in ['dev', 'stage', 'prod']] }%"

- name: print the group
  debug:
    msg: "My site is {{ my_site }}"
```

That obviously doesn't work, however.

Has anyone solved this problem before?

Note: I'm using Ansible 2.2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be achieved in several ways probably.

Here's a fix for the Jinja2 template (you should use [Jinja2 syntax](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#for) not Python inside):

```
vars:
  list1:
    - list1element1
    - list1element2
  list2:
    - list2element1
    - list2element2

tasks:
  - set_fact:
      list3: "{% for prefix in list1 %}{% for postfix in list2 %}{{ prefix }}-{{ postfix }} {% endfor %}{% endfor %}"

  - debug:
      var: list3.split(' ')
```

Comment: Thanks for that!  It's a bit ugly, but definitely works!